# How to make a moving div have a fixed-overlayed element inside?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to overlay a menu over an image but the container of the image is variable. I don't know where the image will be or how big it is. How can I position something absolute/fixed over an image without knowing where to set the top, left coordinates?

```
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #282828;
  padding: 0;
}
.moving-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.content {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.overlay {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

<body>
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="moving-container">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
        <div class="overlay">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here's an [example that doesn't work](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOZjBZ). You can see how the blue-border box that's the overlay object is pushed below the white-colored full-span div.

If I use position absolute, however or fixed, I get [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWwxdP).

I've tried to set the image as a background of the element, and then the inside of the element would be the menu, but without knowing how big the element is eg. a fixed px value, the background image won't appear (which is bigger than the menu itself).

So what do I do? I've come across translate, but I have not implemented that before.

In the examples above I have a fixed height dimension to work with where width is just 100%.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a psedoclass to accomplish this task. No matter what the dimensions of `.foo` are, the inner overlay will cover the entire area.

```css
.foo {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.foo::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that after selector? Not sure what the double colon means in CSS use. It turns out I can do this with position absolute inside a position relative, gahhh... I mean I'm glad I found a solution but man... if you hadn't answered this question would be deleted. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You should read a bit about CSS pseudo-classes. You'll be using those double `::` in no time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Comment: I think I might have seen them for something like a hover selector but not sure. Thanks for the link.